# XAMPP - "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"

Tags: php, windows, xampp, ini

I have `XAMPP` running on my system in Windows environment.. However, I never got `"Scan this dir for additional .ini files"` to load any additional php.ini file that I have in my projects... How do I do that in Windows environment?

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really [documented](http://php.net/php-ini-scanned-files) but the --with-config-file-scan-dir compile option. Meaning you'd have to build your own version of PHP to set that directory.
Kind of late but the compiler option will just set the default location.
Compiling PHP every time you want to change that would be painful.
You can use the PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR env variable to make it happen.

Comment: I don't have write access to my windows folder at work. What if you can't edit the php.ini file in your end?

Comment: If you use apache as webserver, you can use .htaccess for custom user ini files.
Document at http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php